# Wrap HTML around text

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is not ideal, but I am running out of options on trying to wrap some HTML around a heading that I have. It is possible at all to target a header text and wrap HTML around that text?

Starting text:

```
<div class="header-intro-text">
   <h1>New Business Conference</h1>
 </div>
```

Ending Text with added HTML

```
<div class="header-intro-text">
   <h1><a href="#">New Business Conference</a></h1>
 </div>
```

Comment: yes. You can try using the innerHTML of `$('.header-intro-text')` and doing a find replace on it and then replacing the innerHTML

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
$(".header-intro-text h1").wrapInner('<a href="#"></a>');
```

Comment: I like this better :) I was coming up with the manual approach. Lesson learned. Need to improve jQuery-fu haha

Comment: @Dan no probs, Dan! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do the following with jQuery:

```
$('h1').html('<a href="#">' + $('h1').text() + '</a>');
```

or for multiple headers

```
$('h1').each(function() {
    $(this).html('<a href="#">' + $(this).text() + '</a>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var hit = $('.header-intro-text h1');
var hitText = hit.text();
hit.html($('<a href="#"></a>').text(hitText));
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qwertynl/reV9V/

Answer (score -1):

```
var word = 'Conference';

function highlight(word){
    var $container = $('.header-intro-text');
    $container.html(
        $container.html().replace(word, '<a href="#">'+word+'</a>')
    );
}
```

Comment: You should definitely cache your reference to the jquery object - you're repeating the selection!